# change the url ceo/edit-member.php?id=123 to ceo/edit-member/123 through web.config

Tags: php, web-config

I have to change the url from ceo/edit-member.php?id=123 to ceo/edit-member/123 through web.config

I am using below code but not working . Please help me out....

```
<rule name="Redirect to edit-member.php" stopProcessing="true">
    <match URL=".*" />
        <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^edit-member/([^/]+)/?$" />
            </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="edit-member.php?id={R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
 </rule>
```